# Цикл по элементам

Tags: javascript, wordpress

Пытаюсь реализовать следующее: при нажатии на кнопку она берет `data-title` из элемента `h1` и передает в скрытое поле CF7. Но скрипт почему-то запоминает только первый элемент, а другие не берет в счет.

Надо, чтобы при нажатии на конкретную кнопку(принадлежащую блоку), брался конкретный `data-title` и заполнял `textarea`.

html

```
<div class="one">
    <h1 data-title="Clicked 1" class="get">Clicked 1</h1>
    <button name="send_1" onclick="send_in();">first</button>
</div>
<div class="two">
    <h1 data-title="Clicked 2" class="get">Clicked 2</h1>
    <button name="send_1" onclick="send_in();">second</button>
</div>
<div class="three">
    <h1 data-title="Clicked 3" class="get">Clicked 3</h1>
    <button name="send_1" onclick="send_in();">third</button>
</div>

<textarea id="myTextarea_1" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
```

script

```
function send_in() {
    var model_buy = $('.get').attr('data-title');
    $('#myTextarea_1').val(model_buy);
}
```

Comment: Продолжение после "но она почем": Но скрипт почему-то запоминает только первый элемент, а другие не берет в счет. Подскажите, как тут цикл реализовать или что нужно

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Такой код возмёт `data-title` от блока, на который кликнули, и поместит результат в `textarea`:

```
<div class="one">
    <h1 data-title="Clicked 1" class="get">Clicked 1</h1>
    <button class="get_btn" name="send_1">first</button>
</div>
<div class="two">
    <h1 data-title="Clicked 2" class="get">Clicked 2</h1>
    <button class="get_btn" name="send_1">second</button>
</div>
<div class="three">
    <h1 data-title="Clicked 3" class="get">Clicked 3</h1>
    <button class="get_btn" name="send_1">third</button>
</div>

<textarea id="myTextarea_1" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
```

```
jQuery( document ).ready(
    function($) {
        $( '.get_btn' ).each(
            function() {
                $(this).on( 'click', function( event ) {
                    $( '#myTextarea_1' ).val( $(event.target).prev().attr('data-title') );
                } )
            }
        );
    }
);
```

Comment: Мне нужно чтобы по отдельности. Идея такова, что при нажатии на конкретную кнопку(принадлежащую блоку), берется конкретный data-titlle и заполняет textarea

Comment: Отредактируйте текст вопроса тогда, в соответствии с этим комментарием.

Comment: Отредактировал вопрос и ответ. Слегка изменил код html.

Answer (score 0):

Так?

```
<div class="one">
        <h1 data-title="Clicked 1" class="get">Clicked 1</h1>
        <button name="send_1" onclick="send_in(event);">first</button>
    </div>
    <div class="two">
        <h1 data-title="Clicked 2" class="get">Clicked 2</h1>
        <button name="send_1" onclick="send_in(event);">second</button>
    </div>
    <div class="three">
        <h1 data-title="Clicked 3" class="get">Clicked 3</h1>
        <button name="send_1" onclick="send_in(event);">third</button>
    </div>
    
    <textarea id="myTextarea_1" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>

function send_in(event){
        document.querySelector('#myTextarea_1').value = event.target.parentNode.firstElementChild.dataset.title
    }
```